When i create a blog and add an image to it, the blog of the that image is created and Published and search a blog to show both ? how to solve it?

I have created a blog on my website and added images. However, when I search on Google, both the image (Media) and the blog are showing up, but I only want the blog to appear. For example, the blog name is 'Salesforce Builder,' and the image name is also 'Salesforce Builder,' so both are showing up. I have attached some screenshots below. How can I solve this issue?

are you referring to attachment pages?

No, we are not referring to attachment pages.

can you add more detail then to explain what is being shown in your screenshot and provide examples? What you said in the question sounds exactly like attachment pages, aka the page that WordPress creates for every media attachment that gets uploaded ( not the direct URL of the image but its page within the CMS, e.g. https://example.com/2024/09/09/image/ vs https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/image.png

I was able to load the URL in the screenshot and inspect the body tag and saw it has class="attachment attachment-template-default single single-attachment postid-42767 attachmentid-42767 attachment-png these are indeed attachment pages! Just to reiterate "attachments" are things that you upload to WordPress and appear in the media library in WP Admin, they have their own post type and that's what you're seeing here, and those pages can be disabled, but that's already been asked here many times and it's mentioned on the official WP dev blogs

This is my original blog post: "https://twopirconsulting.com/elevate-your-ultimate-marketing-strategy-with-marketing-cloud-personalization/". While the blog is fine, I have added some images, such as "Marketing Cloud Personalization". However, when I search on Google, both the image blog (media) "https://twopirconsulting.com/marketing-cloud-personalization/" and my regular blog appear in the results. I need a solution to prevent the image blog from showing up in search results. Please provide a Solution.
